# Android Studio: How to close shortcut list tab

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

i'm probably dumb but i'm not able to find a way to close that tab in android studio (i don't even know how did I opened it) with "Search everywhere Double Shift Go To File Ctrl+maiusc+N etc.."
sorry I know it's a silly question but I can't find a way, neither on the internet... thank you in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Click once inside the panel and once outside and it goes away

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.... maybe I'm clicking in the wrong place?

Comment: I misunderstood what it was that you were referring to. As explained in some of the answers this is like an onboarding options menu to get you started. If you don't care for any of the actions go to the Project tab on your left and select the files you want to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a tab. It is an screensaver which is shown when you have no files opened. Why do you want to close it?

If you want to see a Welcome Screen close all projects using File | Close Project action.

Comment: I was too dumb to understand it, thank you very very much!

Comment: Please accept the answer if you agree with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the default screen when no project is opened or no file in a project is opened.

You should try browsing file manager and double click files to open.

Stay Safe.Code Happy.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can try pressing  **CTRL+W** or **CTRL+F4** in order to close opened tabs in Android Studio

Comment: I tried but it's non properly a tab, it's more like a "mask", i don't know how to name it, i just uploaded the screenshot